# Laravel ext-mcrypt missing macOS

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew, mcrypt

I am currently trying to import a previous laravel project a few other students worked on but I am having trouble running the composer commmand "composer install" in the project. It is requesting I have ext-mcrypt which I cannot seem to install at all. I am also using homebrew. I get the following errors.[image]

Online I find a few guides saying to run the command `brew install php56-mcrypt` `brew install php5-mcrypt brew install homebrew/core/php71-mcryptbrew install homebrew/core/php56-mcrypt` with errors such as:[image]

I was successfuly able to install `brew install mcrypt` but after when I run composer install I get the same error

Comment: What is your version of php?

Comment: You have to make sure you are pointing to the right PHP...

Comment: I edited your question to remove the [brew] tag; it has nothing to do with Homebrew.